# Using AngularJS and AJAX to Validate Email Addresses Against Database

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, forms

I have an `<input>` tag in my form:

```
<input type="email" name="Email_i" placeholder="enter email here" id="e_mail" onBlur="loadDoc(this.value)">
```

After the input loses focus, the following function is called that uses AJAX:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var no = document.getElementById("e_mail").value;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?email="+no, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And here is the PHP logic from `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_GET['email'];

include "config.php";

$check = mysql_query("select * from registration_form where EMail ='$email' and EMail <> ''",$con);
if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1)
{
    echo '<p style="color:#ff0000">Email Already Exists</p>';
    $_SESSION['email'] = "yes";
}
else
{
    echo '<p style="color: #00ff00">available</p>';
}
```

I want to do this operation using AngularJS, that verifies the email address from the database, but it's not working. Can you help me?

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting and grammar and tags of the post a bit to make the question more clear. It's still not clear to me exactly where you are stuck. You should  show exactly what problems you're having with your code example above. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to validate an email address. If the Email address is existing in the table, the user is not proceeded with the insertion. Because user is suppose to enter an email address which is unique. I have done it through server- side validation using PHP by comparing it with `mysql_error()==1062` but I want it to be done using AngularJS or AJAX. I have tried the above code. But it ends up resulting the user being able to insert the data. (Here for the Ajax and AngularJS part am testing it with table's unique index removed.)